# How to correcly use HTML tags in translation Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a code `<span>{{ trans('lang.color.' . $bet->color) }}</span></div>` which displays the bet amount for a specific color.

My **lang** file:

```
    'color' => [
    'red' => 'red',
    'zero' => 'green',
    'black' => 'black',
               ],
```

Which is responsible for the fact that if the bet was placed on red, the site will say: set to red.
How can I correctly display HTML code in color variables? For example, if i write `'red' => '<div style="font-color:#FF0000">red</div>'` site does not convert the text to HTML, and writes the div with text. How to make read text file HTML?

My laravel version: 5.1.10.

Comment: Wrap your `trans()` function in `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures for details (scroll down to *"If you don't want the data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:"*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Displaying Unescaped Data

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```php
{!! trans('lang.color.' . $bet->color) !!}
```

> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to escape any HTML entities in the content.